# How to synchronize a process with random number of active threads?

Tags: linux, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore, barrier

I have the following problem. My process spawns 4 threads, which perform the same task independently and need to wait for all of them to finish the processing before going to the next processing iteration. However, the number of active threads, i.e., the number of threads processing data and which need to wait for the others to finish is variable from 1 to 4. For instance, some times 2 threads will process data and they need to wait each other before continuing.

I've have read that barriers could do that for me, however, when they are created I've got to specify the number of threads to wait, which is not the case with my application. Additionally, due to the way the application was implemented, it would be awkward and complex to keep creating/destroying barriers every time.

I was wondering if there is another way to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: First question would be in which language your program is implemented with.

Comment: @Adonis, it is in C.

Comment: You said, "my process spawns 4 threads" as if that's what it _always_ does, and then you said, "some times 2 threads will process data..."  So, does that mean that when two threads are processing data, there are two other threads _not_ processing data? If so, then what are the other two doing? Are they just waiting? If so, then why not have them wait on the same barrier that the two active threads are using?

Comment: @SolomonSlow, there always are 4 threads, however, the data producers feeding them are random, so in the example I gave, two of them are waiting on a conditional variable for the presence of new data. The idle threads can not wait on the same place as they are waiting for the cond. variable while the other threads are processing.

Comment: So, you're saying that an "idle" thread is a thread that might start working at any time? I don't know how you can possibly decide whether they have all finished the task if you have no way of knowing when any one of them might _start_ the task.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve it using Semaphore.

```
// Global Sempahore initialized to zero.
Sempahore global_sempahore(0)

// Your main thread which spawns your 'n' worker thraeds.
// After spawning 'n' threads your main thread will wait for those threads to finish.
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    global_sempahore.sem_wait();
}


// This is your worker thread routine.
// After processing the common work routine before exiting each thread will signal the sempahore.
global_sempahore.sem_post();
```

The idea is initialize the sempahore in locked mode with 0.
After spawning your *n* worker threads in main thread wait on sempahore for *n* times.

In worker thread just before exit signal the semaphore.

This will ensure that main thread will wake up only when all *n* threads finished executing.